# readBin issue with "double" data in R

Tags: r, bin

I collect 3D excitation-emission spectra on a PerkinElmer LS-50B using FL winlab software (the classic Perkin Elmer vendor software for the device). For this mode, the software apparently allow only to save *.sp file (specific binary file from Perkin Elmer) and save one file per each excitation increment.

I would like to read the file into R. I found a
[Mathlab script here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22736-perkinelmer-ir-data-file-import-tools)
And I am trying to do the same.

The first part look good
I put an sp [example file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3u2o1g203uoxe4/BS02_070421%2305.sp?dl=0)

```
filename <- file.choose()

fid <- file(filename, "rb")
  
 # check if PE file
 signature <-  readBin(fid,"character",n=4L); print(signature)
  
 description <- readBin(fid, "character", n=40L)

DataSetDataMember= -29828 #this is given by Perkin Elmer

 while (!blockID==DataSetDataMember) # find out data block
      {
       blockID <- readBin(fid,'int', n=1L, size=2) # 16 bits
      } 

 innerCode <- readBin(fid,'int' ,n=1L, size=2)
  len <- readBin(fid,'int' ,n=1L, size=4)
```

then if I follow the [Mathlab script](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22736-perkinelmer-ir-data-file-import-tools)
I am supposed to do something like:

```
df <- readBin(fid, 'double', n= len/8, size=8); head(df)
```

I know by collecting the data that the data have 1 column and 696 rows and reading on the Fluorometer screen that the five first rows are

```
26.551
22.92912
19.24006
15.62411
13.27673
```

In my current script, I get the right number of data but unfortunately not the right values. I get something like:

```
length(df)
696
head(df)
[1]  2.304505e+106 -1.515661e+170 -1.039620e-170  -2.655188e+98   2.632235e-74
```

I tried several combinations with different `size`  but still don't get what I am supposed to get. Not sure where is the problem.

Comment: (1) What is `len` used for? (2) Why `245547008` if `696` is the correct length? (3) How is the bin file created, how do you "know" that the first number is `26.551`? It's a little difficult helping with this since we don't have the raw file to play with.

Comment: I modified the original question to answer what is len and why is  245547008

Answer (score 0):

*If* they were written as 64-bit doubles *then* reading them as `double` restores them:

```
> values <- sqrt(1:4)
> values
[1] 1.00000 1.41421 1.73205 2.00000
> tf <- tempfile()
> writeBin(values, tf)
> chk <- readBin(tf, "double", n=4)
> chk
[1] 1.00000 1.41421 1.73205 2.00000
> identical(chk, values)
[1] TRUE
>
```

My suggestions in these situation is to test the flow both ways with simpler finger exercise such as this one.